# Disable all Microsoft Office macros globally for all users

Tags: microsoft-office, macros, windows-server-2012-r2

Due to popular "locky" and similar malware out there I need to **disable macros** for all installed **Microsoft Office** products (Word, Excel...) globally for **any user** who logs in into a particular server running Windows Server 2012 R2.

How to do that?

The server is not a domain controller, so I have no Administrative templates available, as suggest some resources I've read.

Thank you!

Comment: I hope you know that there are other infection vectors that locky uses, and only disabling office macros, won't provide 100% protection from that malware.  We need to know more about your server configuration in order to help.

Comment: @Ramhound they use also .js files, but that is handeled via having enabled Internet Explorer Enhanced Security (IEES) which disables all but whitelisted sites/files to run javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done via Group Policy with appropiate Administrative Templates present. This HOWTO is for machines with no GPO central store [1]. You might use the classic templates (ADM) [2], or the new ones (ADMX). **I recommend ADMX**, not only because it is newer and not obsolete, but mainly because it allows you to browse `All Settings` in the GPOs at once.

1. Download the templates: go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download and search for "Office 20xx Administrative Template files", where xx is your Office version installed.
2. Extract the files to some temporary location (it is usually a self-extracting exe, or msi package). Here is how to extract files from msi [3].
3. Copy all the ADMX files into `%systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\` and included language files into `%systemroot%\PolicyDefinitions\<appropiate_language_directory>` (probably `en-US`)
4. Set-up the GPOs:

   1. under User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Microsoft Office 20xx -> Security Settings -> enable the **Disable VBA for Office applications**.
   2. [optional] you might also want to enable the **Disable All ActiveX** option in the same branch.
   3. go to User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Microsoft  20xx ->  Options -> Security -> Trust Center -> enable the **VBA Macro Notification Settings** as "Disable all without notification"

hint: Group Policy Editor is "gpedit.msc"

[1] https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/929841/how-to-create-the-central-store-for-group-policy-administrative-template-files-in-windows-vista

[2] https://superuser.com/a/1073064/440382

[3] [How do I extract files from an MSI package?](https://superuser.com/questions/307678/how-to-extract-files-from-msi-package)

Comment: this, unfortunately, causes a very unpleasant macro warning popup window error: https://superuser.com/questions/1499625/multiple-macro-warning-message-popups-when-more-than-one-ms-word-window-is-opene :(

Answer (score 1):

It can be done via Group Policy with appropiate Administrative Templates installed/imported.

1. Download the templates: go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download and search for "Office 20xx Administrative Template files", where xx is your Office version installed.
2. Import them to Group Policy Editor: right click on User Configuration -> Administrative Templates and click "Add/Remove Templates" -> Add -> browse to the folder you saved the templates to (browse to the ADM folder) -> OK
3. Set it all up:

   1. under User Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Clasic Administrative Templates (ADM) -> Microsoft Office 20xx -> Security Settings -> enable the **Disable VBA for Office applications**
   2. in the same branch select all product you want to have macros disabled (typically Word, Excel and Powerpoint) and go to Microsoft  20xx ->  Options -> Security -> Trust Center -> enable the **VBA Macro Notification Settings** as "Disable all with notification"

hint: Group Policy Editor is "gpedit.msc"

Comment: The author's machines are not connected to a domain controller, so using group policy, will be sort of tough to enforce.

Comment: Yes.. I've seen hints like this... but I do not have it there. When I go to Group policy editor -> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> All Settings ... there is no "VBA Macro..."

Neither it is in "User Configuration" branch

Comment: go to start and type gpedit.msc and hit enter

Comment: Why can't you just add the required Administrative templates, it would take, literally 30 seconds to install.

Comment: @TheStarvingGeek I know how to get to the correct console, but it is not there

Comment: @Ramhound because I haven't figured out how to add them even though I surfed both DuckDuckGo/Google and/or Microsoft/Technet :(

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35554 download the template here

Comment: in gpediter right click on "Administrative Templates" and click "Add/Remove templates" then "Add" then browse to the template

Comment: @TheStarvingGeek The problem is that I need it for Office 2010 and when I search for it, it indeed, finds it, but in the "System Requirements" there is no "Windows Server 2012", only 2008 :/

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18968 go here then

Comment: @crysman You should edit your question and mention the version of Office you are using.  This way you avoid, long discussions, like the above comments.  [Related Question: How do I import ADMX files for Microsoft Office 2013?](http://serverfault.com/questions/486426/how-do-i-import-admx-files-for-microsoft-office-2013)

Comment: I even just tested to make sure it would work on server 2012 and it does

Comment: [Office 2016 Administrative Template files (ADMX/ADML) and Office Customization Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49030)

Comment: OK, I've downloaded it and imported it to Local Group Policy Editor -> User Configuration -> Administrative Templates, even though Windows Server 2012 is not supported. And... yes, it works! Thank you all!

Comment: One more issue, though, If I enable just the option "Disable VBA for Office applications", it seems not working properly (it is not grayed-out).

On the contrary, when I go to e.g. Microsoft Excel 2010 -> Excel Options -> Security -> Trust Center and enable the "VBA Macro Notification Settings", it is grayed-out in the menu (no reboot needed)

So... It seems I have to Enable all the options - I mean explicitely for every Office application multiple times and also possibly the first option mentioned here to be sure.

Am I right?

Comment: try to run a macro