# Multiple macro warning message popups when more than one MS Word window is opened

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, macros, group-policy

I've disabled macros for MS Office products via GPO like this: https://superuser.com/a/1176677/440382. Unfortunately, this causes a very weird error in MS Word (both versions 2016 and 2013):

**multiple alert windows pop up warning about macros** (something like "*The function you are attempting to run contains macros or content that requires macro language support...*"):
[image]

**despite** in GPO (AD Group Policy) there is *"**Disable all without notification**"* which also might be seen in local MS Word options itself:
[image]

This error occurs **only when you open a second MS Word window**. When only one .DOC(X) file is opened, there is no such a problem.

Unfortunately, this problem occurs even when there are no macros whatsoever in the DOC(X) file(s).

Any ideas, how to fix it? It is VERY frustrating for our users...

PS:

- I need to have macros globally disabled, because of security reasons
- sorry for screenshots in Czech, that is how the software runs here...

related threads:

1. https://superuser.com/a/1176677/440382

Comment: anyone, please? :/

Comment: I've tested it today again on random two machines, and no issue! Interesting. We've been having this issue for several months! I therefore speculate it got resolved by some MS update (?)

Answer (score 0):

You could check for any addons that have modules installed or for any code in `Personal` workbook of the specific user.

Comment: Negative. Had been tested on various machines under various users, even fresh installs - does not depend on anything in workbook. More info here: https://superuser.com/questions/1499625/multiple-macro-warning-message-popups-when-more-than-one-ms-word-window-is-opene/1545475#comment2359421_1499625

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error after disabling VBA in MS Office. It was popping up whenever I opened a document, even a blank one.

[image]

Turned out to be an Adobe PDF addin as the cause:

[image]