# How to extract the files from a MSI when you only see .rsrc .data with 7z?

Tags: 7-zip, windows-installer

`7zip` can usually open .exe or .msi installers and see all the files.

However in the case of, for example, https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/python-2.7.18.msi we only see:

[image]

How can we extract all files from this .msi (is should contain `python.exe` etc.).

Here it's just an example with Python 2.7 (which is EOL) but it's a general question.

Comment: For extracting an MSI file you don't need 7-Zip: https://superuser.com/questions/307678/how-do-i-extract-files-from-an-msi-package

Comment: @Robert for me this doesn't do a simple extraction "independent of the current system". Example: since this MSI is already installed in my system, I can't extract the original files from the MSI; the command you suggest gives this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ixi3.png and then it's stuck (probably because it's already installed on the system). I'm looking for a solution which is independent of the current system, just extract the files.