# USB 3.0 Media Windows 7 Setup

Tags: windows-7, usb, boot

I just got TWO new SanDisk Extreme USB 3.0 32GB
I use the Windows 7 USB DVD download to make it bootable.
I connected it to a computer on a USB 2.0 port and
Windows 7 boots perfectly from the USB drive 3.0. But at the advance setting to choose a partition (upgrade or Advance, cleaning all partitions and re doing it)

It just refuses to install and gives an error:

> We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one. For more information, see the Setup log files

I have tried to use these TWO USB 3.0 media devices on different computers and all of them give the same error.
If I use USB 2.0 Media all is perfect.

I have tried to clean partitions, change setting in BIOS, change boot order, change IDE/AHCI and connect on different SATA ports on the 4 computers I have in the lab for testing.

Comment: `For more information, see the Setup log files` What was in those log files?

Comment: Where would you even find those log files?  The installation was done from an ISO.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 pre-dates common support for USB 3.0, thus has no drivers for it or XHCI booting support. Windows didn't get native USB 3.0 and XHCI support until Windows 8.

You would need to obtain drivers from your motherboard manufacturer and install them in order for Windows 7 to be able to use your USB 3.0 media. You probably can't do this during the Windows installation though, so you would have to slipstream the drivers into your Windows installation media beforehand.

You are also likely to require a motherboard with UEFI instead of BIOS.

Related questions:
[How does one install Windows 7 using USB 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/278888/how-does-one-install-windows-7-using-usb-3)
http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/32302-How-to-install-Windows-7-from-a-USB-3-0-Thumb-Drive-(FAST-installation!)