# boot win 7 from external usb 3.0 bsod on each try?

Tags: windows-7, boot, external-hard-drive, bsod, slipstream

Recently I have installed win 7 on my external usb 3.0 sata 500gb hdd, using wintousb and rufus I was able to do so pretty easily.

The issues arise when I try to take advantage of usb 3.0 speed for my external Os drive, each time I try so it gets stuck on bsod.

In search of a solution I came across this article:

[How does one install Windows 7 using USB 3?](https://superuser.com/questions/278888/how-does-one-install-windows-7-using-usb-3)

which tells to slipstream drivers into usb stick to get advantage of usb 3.0 on during installation, I am not much familiar with slipstream but I can easily do the command part.

Can I add usb 3.0 drivers to boot entries of win 7 as a patch?

Does the usb installer flash made from above article do so by default?

What procedures I need to follow to add usb 3 support in my win7 installation?

Answer (score -1):

I encountered similar problem. I bought new SSD for work on linux and I kept the old SSHD in usb3.0 external case, which I planned to be used for gaming.
I run into BSOD each time I try to boot from USB 3.0 during Win7 logo animation.
Scrolling through various forums, I found a probable cause.
Did you install your new instance of Win7 on MBR or GPT-based partition?
It is said that the BSOD is caused by a flaw of MFT. I also read that combination of installing the system on GPT and installing USB 3.0 drivers prior to booting from usb3.0 might help.
Since you have a fresh instance, you might give it a try.
Anyway, please share the results ;)
Good luck.

Comment: Windows 7 cannot be installed from a 3.0 storage device unless you add the drivers to the .ISO being used.  So there isn't a "flaw" its by design.

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.